# How can I check out the balance on my Vodafone Italy SIM card without a mobile app?

Tags: italy, cellphones

I purchased a SIM card from Vodafone in Italy, which costs €30 and includes 8 GB of data. Now I want to check the balance of my SIM card.

According to [SIM card wiki](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Italy) Vodafone Italy offers an iOS app. But it is only available in the Italian App Store, and since I don't like to change the store region, [I could not install it](http://prepaid-data-sim-card.wikia.com/wiki/Provider_Apps).

Another source is to call *404* as [instructed here](https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100418015825AAD8lpW), but it only tells me how much credit is left on the account, which in my case was €2.51, and does not tell me the current monthly balance on the data.

I asked a staff but she told me usually the customer checks it on the mobile app, and in the store she only told me the €2.51 credit, not on the amount of data I can use.

So is there any way to check out how many GB I can use right now?

Comment: Perhaps also check USSD codes? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vodafone+italy+ussd+codes&oq=vodafone+italy+ussd

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Browse to http://contatori.vodafone.it/ using your SIM card data connection. You will find some useful graphs.

Swipe to "La tua offerta" section. This will tell you how much data you can use up to what day/month. At the bottom there's your credit displayed.

[[image: Vodafone data counters exmple]]

Another option is to register to http://www.vodafone.it site and login in your private area. The site is available only in italian.

Please note that from September 2016 *404* and *414* numbers are no more toll free.

Comment: Perfetto! Grazie per la tua risposta! - I understand Italian a bit and have no problem on the page. Just turning off WiFi before opening the page, otherwise it doesn’t show the account detail.